# Doob Decomposition Theorem - submartingale iff increasing

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

Probability with Martingales

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

To prove $b$ I tried:

$$A_n \ge A_{n-1}$$

$$\iff E[X_{n} - X_{n-1} | \mathscr F_{n-1}] \ge 0$$

$$\iff E[X_{n} | \mathscr F_{n-1}] \ge X_{n-1}$$

That suffices to show 'if' but what about 'only if'?

I think I can conclude that $P(A_n \ge A_{n+1}) = 1 \ \forall n$, but how do I conclude $P(A_n \le A_{n+1} \ \forall n$) = 1? I think I need [right continuity or something](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1150297/difference-between-modification-and-indistinguishable)? I remember indistinguishable vs modification being discussed in classes, but I think it wasn't discussed at this point in the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is discrete time, so right continuity is not an issue. It is simply the fact that if $P[D_n]=1$ for all $n$ then $P\left[\cap_n D_n\right]=1$ (and conversely).

Comment: John Dawkins, do we really have that $$P(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} D_n) = 1 \iff P(D_n) = 1 \ \forall n \ge 1$$? I mean, 'only if' follows by monotonicity of probability but what about 'if' ?

Comment: @BCLC to see why this is true, try to prove the complement has measure probability

Comment: @BCLC, see Proposition 2.4(a) on page 25 of  *Probability with Martingales*.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Thanks! ^-^